# Comparison of SDFs with Normal Map Rendering for 2D Sprites

Tags: normal-mapping, signed-distance-field

**Prior note:** I very drastically edited this question after understanding that SDFs and normal map rendering "do not solve the same problem." (Thank you, @DMGregory.) However, the question's essence remains the same: Trying to understand the difference between SDFs and normal maps, their roles, and why they both exist, *in terms of their use for 2D sprites*.

### Question:

*In terms of their use for 2D sprites*, when are SDFs used over normal map rendering, and vice versa, and when are both of these used simultaneously? Why?

Please outline a table or list of differences, and how these apply to different types of 2D sprites. Useful criteria include, but are not limited to, use cases, popularity, performance, general compatibility, VFX, *etc*.

I wouldn't hate to know about any specific points of view regarding virtual board game tiles and cards. However, I'd also like to be able to use the most appropriate answer as a reference for any other games I might make in the future as well, not just board games (*e.g.* 2D platformers, roguelikes, and so forth).

Comment: These two techniques do not solve the same problem, so I'm struggling to think of any situation where you would need to choose between them. SDFs are good for making single-colour vector-like graphics, like glyphs in a font, that work well at multiple resolutions or support effects like dynamic outlines, shadows, glows cheaply. Normal maps are used for applying lighting and shading, by modelling surface detail that catches or occludes light. Can you edit your question to clarify what kind of sprite you're trying to draw to which both these could apply, and why you don't just use both for it?

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you so much for pointing that out. I apologise for my confusing question, and lack of clarity. I think my question originated from a misconception regarding what SDFs really are, in comparison to normal maps. As you so kindly pointed out, they don't really solve the same problem, and can be used simultaneously. I should have investigated further before asking. Your comment is really what answers my question. Would you like me to delete the question, or should I just wait for it to be closed? Thanks again for clarifying things up for me, I appreciate it.

Comment: You can go ahead and delete it if you like. Or you could try editing it to ask "What are SDFs and Normal Maps used for in sprite rendering?" outlining what your current understanding was when you posted this question. Then I or another user could write up a proper answer to clear up any misconceptions. That can help future readers who get into the same confusion that you did.

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you for your insight. I've edited the question accordingly to your kind suggestion.

Comment: Can you briefly define each of the techniques, as you previously understood them? Or even in what context you heard about them that made them sound like rival techniques? That'll help focus the question on a specific misunderstanding to clear up, rather than open-ended lists of information about each.